# Restlet static content served from multiple sources

Tags: restlet

My application needs to be able to serve up static content which can be contained in a number of different places (directories and/or via the class loader). So, for example, a resource /static/file.html might be found in /dir1/file.html or /dir2/file.html; I would want it to try /dir1, and if not found there, then /dir2, and so on.

With servlets in Jetty, I can use either a HandlerList of DefaultServlet, to sequentially try to handle the request from each directory until satisfied, or even easier a single DefaultServlet with a ResourceCollection.

I can't see a way to do something similar in restlet, without writing a class to specifically do this. I could modify Directory to handle multiple sources (in a similar way to DefaultServlet with ResourceCollection), or write a new Restlet which tries each contained Restlet sequentially, until successfully handled (like HandlerList). But before I do that, am I missing another way that already exists to achieve this?

thanks,
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that Directory doesn't know how to handle multiple source directories. It would be a nice to add support for this and contribute it back.